# Visual studio xamarin Tools > Android > menu disabled

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

Suddenly Visual studio 2015 xamarin **Tools > Android > menu disabled**

1. How do I resolved ?[image]
2. What is the reason for this ?

Answer (score 1):

The following solution worked for me :

- Close Visual studio
- Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
- Run in Administrator "SDK Manager.exe"
- Do makes important updates
- Close SDK manager
- Restart Visual studio

Answer (score 0):

the solution to solve this problem :

- to launch uninstaller.exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
- then to do a manual installation
  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/

Now it is OK, the sub menus under Tools / Android are active.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by changing android-sdk path:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
to this:
C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Android\sdk